# say list = [9, 8, 9, 10]. How do I find the location(s) of the 9s for example?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration

## Function

```
def find_value(num_list, target):
    target_loc = []  # list to store the location of the target
    condition = True
    while condition == True:
        for target in num_list:
            if target in num_list:
                index = num_list.index(target)
                target_loc.append(index)
                condition = True
        else:
            condition = False    
    return target_loc
```

## Main program:

```
num_list = keep_positive_numbers()
print()
print("List entered: ", num_list)
print()
target = int(input("Enter target = "))
print()
list = find_value(num_list, target)
print("Target exists at location(s): ", list)
```

## Output

Enter a positive integer: 9
Enter a positive integer: 9
Enter a positive integer: 8
Enter a positive integer: 0

List entered:  [9, 9, 8]

Enter target = 7

Target exists at location(s):  [0, 0, 2]

Comment: How are `[0, 0, 2]` the positions of `7` in `[9, 9, 8]`?

Comment: m8 idek I'm new to programming. Its showing the location of 9 and 8 in the list [9, 9, 8], however it only takes into account the first location of 9.
also I just realized that the target was 7 but its giving the location of the elements present in the list.

Comment: And what is your expected output in general -- and for `[9,8,9,10]` and `9`? `[0, 2]` by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def find_value(num_list, target):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(num_list) if x == target]

find_value([9, 8, 9, 10], 9)
# [0, 2]
```

Or, if you want your explicit loop, use a for-loop over the indexes:

```
def find_value(num_list, target):
    target_loc = []  # list to store the location of the target
    for i in range(len(num_list)):  
        if target == num_list[i]:
            target_loc.append(i)
    return target_loc
```

You have to check indexes one by one. `list.index` always returns the *first* one.

Comment: oh damn okay thanks but is there any other way as I don't think our prof has taught us that so im not sure if I can use this method. If there aren't any then no worries. Thanks a lot again.